# Azure website hiding .html extensions

Tags: html, azure

Im hosting a couple of html files using an Azure website. I want to hide the .html file name extensions. I have been looking trough the site however i didnt find an options that works specifically with Azure websites.

Comment: which technology you are using? if you are using ASP.NET, you can use IIS url rewrite

Comment: Only plain html files.

Comment: You need to modify the .htaccess file present on your server But i am not sure whether you can do that on Azure Websites. Try to contact customer care. Maybe they can help you out

Answer (score 0):

You could use a URL Rewrite in the web.config file for an ASP.NET application to send a 404 or some other response for .html file requests.

Also, you could probably set up a custom HTTP handler mapping for .html extensions. That way a language processor could intercept those requests instead of just serving the file.